# Nested object destructuring and renaming

Tags: javascript, object, ecmascript-6, destructuring

Is it possible to rename a variable when destructuring a nested object in JavaScript? Consider the following code:

```
const obj = {a: 2, b: {c: 3}};
const {a: A, b:{c}} = obj;
```

How can I rename `c` in above code like I renamed `a` to `A`?

```
const {a: A, b:{c}: C} = obj
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Put the `c:C` inside the inner object

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The same way you set a new name for A - `{c: C}`:

```js
const obj = {a: 2, b: {c: 3}};

const {a: A, b:{c: C}} = obj;

console.log(C);
```